# What is the correct definition of magnetic moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, definition, magnetic-moment

I found myself tired of by searching what is the exact definition of magnetic moment.
I have also come across two formulas for same quantity

$\vec{M} = \vec{m} \times \vec{d}$

where $\vec{M}$ is the magnetic moment, $\vec{m}$ is the magnetic pole strength and $\vec{d}$ is the distance between two poles

Another formula

$\vec{M} = \vec{i}\times\vec{A}$

Where $\vec{M}$ is magnetic moment, $\vec{i}$ is electric current and $\vec{A}$ is area vector

So please suggest me which formula is accurate one and give detailed description of this.

Comment: Please use MathJax and edit the equations @Anwesh Panda

Comment: @Lelouch ok i will edit it

Comment: That's better, but you are still not using MathJax.

Comment: Hey where the option for Mathjax

Comment: Just use LaTeX syntax for mathematical formula, including the $

Comment: the magnetic pole strength $m$ is NOT a vector, no vector product in the definition of moment  but $\mathbf{M}=m\mathbf{d}$

Comment: $\vec{M} = \vec{i}\times\vec{A}$ is wrong. Correct would be $\vec{M} = i \vec{A}$, according to [Magnetic moment - Amperian loop model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Amperian_loop_model).

Comment: Thanks for editing guys

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct formulae for ${\boldsymbol \mu}$, although it is hard to find magnetic monopoles so the first is of little use.  Interestingly the two formulae  give different formulae for the force on a magnetic dipole in an inhomogeneous field. The monopole-pair formula gives
$$
{\bf F}_{\rm monopole-pair}=({\boldsymbol \mu} \cdot \nabla) {\bf B} 
$$
while the current loop gives
$$ 
{\bf F}_{\rm current-loop}=  \nabla ({\boldsymbol \mu}\cdot {\bf B}).
$$
These are different in a region with a non-zero current, so in principle one can determine whether a dipole is of the monopole-pair or the current-loop variety. I believe that experiments on neutrons suggest that their magnetic dipole moment obeys  the current-loop force equation.

The usual and practical *definition* of ${\boldsymbol \mu}$ comes from the torque on the dipole being
$$
{\boldsymbol \tau}= {\boldsymbol \mu}\times {\bf B}.
$$
For a general current-distribution one has
$$
{\boldsymbol \mu}= \frac 12 \int d^3x \left({\bf r}\times {\bf J}({\bf r})\right).
 $$
If the current is in a planar loop this last equation reduces to $|{\boldsymbol \mu}|= I 
\times {\rm Area}.$ (Here the "$\times$" is just  multiplication of numbers; in the previous formulae it was the cross-product of vectors.) For a long solenoid one can aproximate the integral by the  length of the solenoid by a pole strength, as in the monopole formula, but this is only a *approximation* as there are no actual poles.

Comment: Hey @mike stone so do we have to consider the 1st formula or the second one

Comment: As I said, the first equation is of little use as there are no monopoles. Applied to the "poles" at the end of a solenoid or bar magnet, it is an approximation because you do  not know exactly where the "poles" are without using the full definition in the volume integral,

Comment: ok understood thank you